# Reusing a defined variable with optional changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to reuse a variable, which is defined at the beginnin of a file (in my case it is a test file).
For some of the tests I have to change a value of the object, but these changes should only be done for this specific test. The next test should use the original object again.

```
const props = {
  id: 'M1234567890',
  update: jest.fn()
}

describe('example()', () => {
  it('should not call update if id is missing', () => {
    // SETUP
    props.id = undefined
    const component = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
    // EXECUTE
    component.instance().example()
    // VERIFY
    expect(props.update).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
  it('should call update', async () => {
    // SETUP
    const component = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
    // EXECUTE
    await component.instance().example()
    // VERIFY
    expect(props.update).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

What I'm doing right now is first defining the 'default' object (`props`) at the beginning of my test file.
Each test is using this object. But some tests need to get a different value for a specific element.
In this case I'm setting the new value, e.g. in the first test I set the `id` to `undefined`.

But in the second test I want to use the 'default' object again.
In my code the second test is also using the new `undefined` (id) value, but I need to use the original object with the `M1234567890` (id) value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is create the variable in a beforeEach block, so you have a clean instance in every test. Especially as you should not reuse the same spy in every test cause this can easily hide wrong behaviour.

```
describe('example()', () => {
  let props
  beforeEach(()=>{
    props = {
      id: 'M1234567890',
      update: jest.fn()
    }
  })
  it('should not call update if id is missing', () => {
    // SETUP
    props.id = undefined
    const component = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
    // EXECUTE
    component.instance().example()
    // VERIFY
    expect(props.update).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
  it('should call update', async () => {
    // SETUP
    const component = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
    // EXECUTE
    await component.instance().example()
    // VERIFY
    expect(props.update).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: Thats the correct way to do it in pretty much every testing framework

Comment: How should I do it if there are nested `describe()` elements? `describe('<Component />', () => { describe('example()', () => { it('should...', () => { }) }) })` Where should I place the beforeEach?

Comment: Not quite sure, I would assume that its enough to put it in the first level `describe` block as it means to run it for every `it` block inside.

Answer (score 0):

You make use of `Object.assign` which specifically helpful for your case.

```
const props = {
  id: 'M1234567890',
  update: jest.fn()
}

describe('example()', () => {
  it('should not call update if id is missing', () => {
    // SETUP
    props.id = undefined
    const component = shallow(<Component {...Object.assign({}, props, {id: undefined})} />)
    // EXECUTE
    component.instance().example()
    // VERIFY
    expect(props.update).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
  it('should call update', async () => {
    // SETUP
    const component = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
    // EXECUTE
    await component.instance().example()
    // VERIFY
    expect(props.update).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

where ever you want to make the changes, you can pass the property you want to change and rest of the object would remain same.

Comment: If I understand your answer code correctly, you have to remove `props.id = undefined`, right?

Comment: yes, because you want it to be undefined, rest of the properties would get copied from `props` object

Comment: Values in `props` will override properties of the first parameter to Object.assign, so it looks like you would need to do something like `Object.assign({}, props, {id: undefined})` if using that method